# GetResponse() in C#

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest

I have the following code in my portable class library. But it gives error that

> `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` does not contain a definition for
>   `GetResponse()`.

```
public async Task<object> GetStateByUserId(string userID)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;
        Stream receiveStream;
        StreamReader readStream;

        request =(HttpWebRequest)CreateGetWebRequest("state/uid/"+userID);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {

        receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        string str = readStream.ReadToEnd().ToString();
        s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<state>(str);
            return s;
        }


    }
```

Anyone know why it is so?

Comment: I have mentioned that in my first line of question

Comment: What kind of application are you writing? Is it a Windows Store application?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) says otherwise; can you show a full stack trace?

Comment: Why aren't you people reading the question? The error is there, and so is the type of app: portable class library.

Comment: No, I am creating PCL which I will use for all mobile platforms.When I use this code on android platform,it works well but while creating PCL ,it gives that error.

Comment: @Suraj That method isn't in the PCL (according to the docs): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx. `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse` appear to be in the PCL.

Comment: Look at this. It might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187347/webheadercollection-httpwebrequest-on-xamarin

Comment: @Tobberoth dont related with you.you can answer the question

Comment: @Suraj Are you actually using the Portable Class Libraries?

Comment: Anyone got the solution?

Comment: @Suraj Contribute more effectively to the question and you might get better quality help... You've made an obvious mistake *assuming* you are using the PCL references, basically you are expecting stuff to exist that doesn't - the error message itself tells you exactly what is wrong. Poke's answer will get you started on what methods are available to the PCL. You can merge that with elements of Shahrooz's answer to get something working.

Comment: I have updated my question.I have given full method implemention. I have written this method in my PCL

Answer (score 8):

If you are writing for targetting the portable class library, you will have to use the asynchronous methods as [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) is not available.

Instead you have to use [BeginGetReponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) and [EndGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.endgetresponse.aspx).

In your case, this could look like this:

```
public void StartRequest ()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)CreateGetWebRequest("state/uid/"+userID);
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishRequest), request);
}

private void FinishRequest (IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;

    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

    // ...
}
```

If you are using .NET 4.5, you can do it like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)CreateGetWebRequest("state/uid/"+userID);
Task<HttpWebResponse> requestTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<HttpWebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, request);
using (var response = await requestTask)
{
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
}
```

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? [Seems correct enough to me.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I’m pretty confused. I have never used PCL myself, but that icon which says “Supported by Portable Class Library” seems clear to me?

Comment: @poke I didn't downvote, because the code is technically correct, but: 1. I think using this old asynchronous pattern in new code is a bad idea, you should use `async`-`await` instead. 2. The documentation is actually confusing, because you *can* use `GetResponseAsync()` in PCL, if you specify certain subset of target frameworks.

Comment: @svick I received the downvotes before adding that example code; and also I used “classic” async code because I didn’t know which .NET version OP was using (at that point, the question wasn’t edited to show the `async` part of the method declaration).

Comment: I have tried this before.But I am getting the same error.@poke sir.

Comment: Same error being *“does not contain a definition for GetResponse()”* or *“does not contain a definition for BeginGetResponse()”*?

Comment: sorry.I was wrong while telling you the output by using your code.It is running well now but I want return object(by converting stream data to object) from this method.It is returning null reference

Comment: @poke sir    Can you tell me how to return object from startrequest() method() .FinishRequest() method will convert stream to custom object and return it to startRequest() method which in turn return that object to calling program  ?                plz............

Comment: You cannot return the result from the StartRequest method. It is executed asynchronously, so you cannot safely say when the request is actually completed. The `FinishRequest` method is however called when it completes, so that will be the only/first place where you can access the result; but at that time, the `StartRequest` method is long over. If you want to consume the result value, you will have to build upon the asynchronous pattern and consume the StartRequest/FinishRequest pair asynchrously as well.

Comment: What if I will use a static member for storing result and access it through its class name ?

Comment: You still won’t be able to tell exactly when you can access that variable. It will only be set after the `Finish` method ran.

Comment: .Net 4.5 version doesn't work... the FromAsync method wont accept the `request.EndGetRequestStream`. It expects a `Func<IAsyncResult,HttpWebResponse>`

Comment: @user1 No idea what I did there; it should be `request.EndGetResponse` that’s passed as the second parameter (just like in the first example). Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the documentation for `GetResponse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse) and compare it with [`GetResponseAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync), you'll notice that in Version information, for example Windows Store apps are missing for `GetResponse()` and other versions of the framework are missing in `GetResponseAsync()`.

Depending on the versions of the framework you chose for your PCL, you might be able to use `GetResponseAsync()` directly (for example if you chose .Net 4.5 and Windows Store, but nothing else).

If you need some of the frameworks that don't support `GetResponseAsync()` out of the box, then I think the best solution here is to use [the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), which will allow you to use `GetResponseAsync()` in other versions of the framework.

Also, switching to `GetResponseAsync()` means you will need to use `await` to get the value, which also means making this method and all methods that call it `async`. (Though confusingly, it seems you already switched to `async` without using `await`, which doesn't make much sense.)