# How to check an internet connection in a Portable class library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, internet-connection

So I would like to check an internet connection in a Portable Class Library.

So far I have used this method [GetResponse() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609528/getresponse-in-c-sharp/20609762#20609762)

But this doesn't return a boolean value to tell me if I have a connection or not.

So far my code looks like this:

```
    public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishRequest), request);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static bool FinishRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but I get an error on the line with `new AsyncCallback()` saying FinishRequest has the wrong return type.. How can I do this?

Please bear in mind that this is in a Portable class library so the method GetResponse() does not exist

Comment: `AsyncCallback` returns void, so `FinishRequest` must do the same. You could create a wrapper class that holds a `HttpWebRequest` and a boolean value and pass that into `BeginGetResponse`. The boolean could then be set in `FinishRequest` as appropriate and referenced from `CheckForInternetConnection`. I don't know if this is the most elegant solution though.

Comment: The reason I avoided this solution is because I dont want the `CheckForInternetConnection()` to return the value of that variable, before the AsyncCallback had executed. E.g. giving me the wrong value

Comment: You could look at [Task.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321448(v=vs.110).aspx) which will allow you to await the resulting task, ensuring nothing continues until the call is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [manualresetevent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
private static ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
  try
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishRequest), request);
    evt.WaitOne();
    return request.HaveResponse;
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
}

private static void FinishRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
  HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
  evt.Set();
}
```